Using path and git dependency for the same dependency
I'm developing two Python packages A and B at the same time, where A uses B as a dependency. Also, I'm using poetry as my dependencies and building manager.
Such as B is still in development and new requirements can be raised at any moment while developing A. I added B as a path dependency in A with the command poetry add /path/to/B --editable.
Nevertheless, using B as a path dependency is not viable for others interested in package A, such as they would require git cloning B. Thus, my pyprojects.toml should define the exact tag of B.
Initially I thought that running these two commands should work:
poetry add git+<IP>/group/B.git@0.1.0
poetry add /path/to/B --editable --group dev

But it raised the following message error:

Incompatible constraints in requirements of A (1.0.0):
B @ file:///path/to/B (0.1.0)
B @ git+http://<IP>/group/B.git@0.1.0 (0.1.0)

I would like to know if this workflow idea is wrong by design and if there is another approach I should follow.
